# Seeking female (later beatnik?) author, used all lowercase

Tags: identification-request

In about 1998, I found a used paperback that I liked, but gave the book away and can no longer remember the author's name.  The book was remarkable in that it used only lowercase letters throughout.  The one story I remember clearly is that she would find abandoned, broken-down cars on the side of the road (maybe fix them or something?) and drive them away.  The stories were generally about her hobo/nomadic adventures - it was probably inspired a lot by 'On The Road'. 
 The author's tone was not trying to be insightful, highbrow or shocking, just documenting a fascinating fun life.

I vaguely remember the cover being a warmer color, maybe orange, and the marketing blurbs mentioning the beat generation, which is why I bought the book in the first place.

I've looked all over at reviews and summaries of female beatnik authors - I don't believe it is one of these:

- Elise Cowen
- Anne Waldman
- Hedwig Gorski
- Edie Parker
- Diane di Prima
- Carolyn Cassady
- Hettie Jones
- Harriet Zwerling
- Joanne Kyger

These two seem possible, but none of their books seem like it:

- Janine Pommy Vega (inspired by 'On The Road')
- Ruth Weiss (because of lowercase fetish, but style/content seems off)

I gave up looking for this long ago, but then thought maybe the internet can help.  If you know the book or author, or where to look, please reply.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please take a the [story identification guide](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info); is there anything else that you remember? The [tour], [ask], and [answer] are also good to look through. I hope that you find the book, and I hope to see you around!

Comment: Hopefully it will attract a contributor with an exhaustive knowledge of the beats. ruth weiss seems like a good guess based on her political use of lowercase. *(I used to consort with poets who had such knowledge, but that was in my younger days;)*  Nevertheless, this is a very interesting question!